# Clicks first link mechanize python

Tags: python, url, mechanize

I have to click a link which i found but when i run that script it clicks the first link how can i fix it ? 
         import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()

br.addheaders = [("User-agent","Chrome")]

br.set_handle_robots(False)

while True:

```
kaynak = br.open("https://temp-mail.org/en/option/change/")

br.select_form(nr=0)

email = br.form.find_control(id='mail', name='mail')

email.value = "something"

submit = br.submit(nr=0)

go = br.open("https://temp-mail.org/en/option/refresh/")

target_text = 'Facebook'

for link in br.links():
    print(link)
    print(link.text)

    if link.text == target_text:
        print('match found')
        break

    br.follow_link(link)
    print(br.geturl())
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your indentaion is off. Your for loop now follows every link it finds, not only the matched one. either place your follow statement inside the `if` before `break`, or after the for loop:

```
for link in br.links():
    print(link)
    print(link.text)

    if link.text == target_text:
        print('match found')
        # Here...
        br.follow_link(link)
        print(br.geturl())
        break

# Or here...
br.follow_link(link)
print(br.geturl())
```